# Iterate C char array of size 100000 takes huge time

Tags: c, string, performance, strcat

Just try to iterate a character array of size 100000 but it takes 8-9 sec.
But for int its takes some milli second.

```c
    int i;
    char str[100005];
    str[0] = '\0';
    for(i=1;i<10000;i++){
        strcat(str, "HelloWorld");
    }
    for(i=1;i<strlen(str);i++){
        str[i]=str[i-1];
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand what strcat does?

Comment: Yes just do concat two string

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Yes. If finds the end of the current string and copies in the contents of the new one.

Comment: You need to set `str[0] = '\0';`

Comment: @MadPhysicist used `str[0] = '\0';` but still it takes huge time

Comment: @AbinashGhosh. That's for correctness. There is a good chance that your allocated memory is already zero-filled. The issue is with the functions you are using.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer and remove your question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
for(i = 1; i < 10000; i++){
    strcat(str, "HelloWorld");
}
```

Think about how that call to `strcat` works. The `strcat` function works by scanning forward in the string until it finds the null terminator character, then writing the second argument there. That's pretty fast if your string is fairly short - say, it's about 10-20 characters long - but if the string you're appending onto is long (say, 10,000 characters), then `strcat` will spend a lot of time simply scanning to the end of the string to find the place at which to append the string. This means that each call to `strcat` in this function will take longer than the previous one, and eventually that last call is fairly slow.

So how can you speed this up? One option would be to store a pointer to the null terminator in the `str` array so that you can tell `strcat` where to start looking. Here's what that might look like:

```
size_t length = strlen("HelloWorld");
char* nextSpot = str;
for(i = 1; i < 10000; i++){
    strcat(nextSpot, "HelloWorld");
    nextSpot += length;
}
```

This means that the `strcat` call will always pick up right where the last one left off, speeding things up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I have to read from a file a do some operation for every char, how to speed up then ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your code. The first is that you are calling `strcat` on a destination array that has not been initialized. You need to set `str[0] = '\0';` first.

The other problems are algorithmic. To know where to insert the target string, `strcat` has to do `strlen` or equivalent every time you call it. That means that it is stepping through `O(n)` characters every time. That makes your algorithm `~O(n^2)`. Then you go and call `strlen` again on every single character, with the same penalty. And keep in mind that the second loop is just setting the entire array to `'H'`.

If you want to copy a string `10000` times, you are better off pre-computing its length and just stepping along the buffer:

```
char str[100005];
const char *template = "HelloWorld";
int n = strlen(template);
char *p = str;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    strncpy(p, template, n);
    p += n;
}
*p = '\0';
```

I am using `strncpy` here because it avoids copying the terminating `'\0'` of `template` for every copy you make.

An alternative approach would be to use modulo division (which would probably be slower) to place the characters:

```
char str[100005];
const char *template = "HelloWorld";
int n = strlen(template);
int end = n * 10000;
for(int i = i; i < end; i++) {
    str[i] = template[i % n];
}
```

Both approaches take a couple of orders of magnitude less time on my machine than your original loop, because they step through the array exactly once.

The final loop copies the previous character over and over into the remainder of the buffer. Since your buffer is filled with `HelloWorld`, the loop copies `'H'` into every location. You can use `memset` to do the same thing for you:

```
memset(str, 'H', 10000 * n);
```

The moral of the story is to avoid recalculating things that you can keep track of with a simple counter or pointer. If you want things to go fast, do as little work as possible.